# Error in Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, cells, type-mismatch

I am having a problem with my code, a compile error "type mismatch". Especially in the following line

```
If comp.Cells(r, c) = "" Then
```

i tried switching r and c with a number separately and it worked, but not together. Here's the full code

```
Sub missing_data()

Dim comp As Worksheet
Set comp = Sheets("Compiled")
empty_cells = 0
sixten_comp = 0
    For r = 2 To 103

        For c = 5 To 18
           'searching for empty cells 
            If comp.Cells(r, c) = "" Then
                If (c + 1998) > comp.Cells(r, 3) Then
                    empty_cells = empty_cells + 1
                    comp.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 13

                    'If comp.Cells(r, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then sixten_comp = sixten_comp + 1

                End If
            End If

        Next c

    Next r

MsgBox "Number of total cells left is " & empty_cells
'MsgBox "Number of total cells left in 16 companies is " & sixten_comp

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any error values (`#N/A` etc) in any of the cells?

Comment: You are getting error because of any one of the cell value may be #N/A

Comment: I had #DIV/0! in some cells. I cleared them and now it works fine

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cells you are checking may contain an error returned by a formula so add another condition to check if the cell doesn't contain an error and if not, proceed to check other conditions....

```
If Not IsError(comp.Cells(r, c)) Then
    If comp.Cells(r, c) = "" Then
        If (c + 1998) > comp.Cells(r, 3) Then
            empty_cells = empty_cells + 1
            comp.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 13
            'If comp.Cells(r, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then sixten_comp = sixten_comp + 1
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
If comp.Cells(r, c).Value = "" Then
```

instead of:

```
If comp.Cells(r, c) = "" Then
```

it should work without a problem

Comment: `.Value` is the default property for a `Range` object, so your two lines are effectively identical.

Comment: @YowE3K what should i use then

Comment: @FranklinVarghese it depends on what is causing the error.  When it crashes, what is the value of `r` and `c`.  What is in the cell at that row / column?  If it is an error code, have a look at the answer just posted by sktneer.